# Copying image from a mask

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv, mask

I have 2 images, the 1st image is the original image and the 2nd image is the mask.
[image: Original image]
[image: Mask]

How can I apply the mask as the opacity or alpha channel for the first image using EmguCV in C#?

Comment: What have you done so far? Except asking this question

Comment: Detecting all white pixels in the 2nd image thru a loop and storing it in an array, then removing all pixels not in the array from the 1st image. But it takes so much time and memory